# How to get the first element of a list from the output of setup module in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I received the following data from the setup module:

```
"ansible_nodename": "3d734bc2a391",
"ansible_os_family": "RedHat",
"ansible_pkg_mgr": "yum",
"ansible_processor": [
  "AuthenticAMD",
  "AMD PRO A10-8700B R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G"
],
"ansible_processor_cores": 1,
"ansible_processor_count": 1,
"ansible_processor_threads_per_core": 1,
```

I want to retrieve the 1st value of `ansible_processor` and use it in a Jinja2 template.

If I use `{{ ansible_processor }}`, it's giving me both values:

```
"AuthenticAMD",
"AMD PRO A10-8700B R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G"
```

But I want only the first one.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

To get first item of the list:

```
- debug:
    msg: "First item: {{ ansible_processor[0] }}"
```

Or:

```
- debug:
    msg: "First item: {{ ansible_processor | first }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this for common handle this situation:

Ref: [get-first-n-elements-of-a-list-in-jinja2-template-in-ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554020/6493535)

```
# from list
- debug:
    msg: "First item: {{ ansible_processor[0] }}"
# from output, like 'https://xxx.xx/xxx/xxx.git'
- debug:
    msg: "git repo's name: {{ (item| urlsplit('path')| basename | splitext)[0] }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `first` filter:

`first` is a `Jinja2` filter, used to get the first value in an array (also known as a list). The last filter can be used to return the last value in an array.

```
- debug:
    msg: "First item in the list: {{ ansible_processor | first }}"
  when: ansible_processor is defined
```

#### Using the array index:

```
- debug:
    msg: "First item in the list: {{ ansible_processor[0] }}"
  when: ansible_processor is defined
```